# Adding an onclick event to a div element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I saw a few similar topics which did help but I have specific problem and didn't manage to solve it alone so if anyone can help out I would appreciate it

I want to add onclick event to a div element.

HTML:

```
<div id="thumb0" class="thumbs" onclick="klikaj('rad1')"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function klikaj(i)
{
    document.getElementById(i).style.visibility='visible';
}
```

Wanted result: div with `id="rad1"` (which is hidden) turns visible, when clicked on div with `id="thumb0"`.

This works when I add it to a button element but don't know how it goes with div elements.

Comment: Are you trying to click on an empty div?

Comment: Is it possible your div is hidden via "display: none" rather than with the visibility: hidden rule?

Comment: Yes basicly it is empty, but has background-image added with css. So I'm kinda trying to click on a image.

Comment: Stephen, if I use display:none then I would have to use display: block to get it visible right? Why do you ask?What did you have in mind?

Answer (score 57):

I'm not sure what the problem is; running the below works as expected:

```
<div id="thumb0" class="thumbs" onclick="klikaj('rad1')">knock knock</div>
​<div id="rad1" style="visibility: hidden">hello world</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
<script>
function klikaj(i) {
    document.getElementById(i).style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>
```

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/5tD4P/

Comment: Ye but both divs have background-image assigned in css. Maybe this would work like you tried just now only if I use img tag in html instead of background-image?!

Comment: @Slovenec if you use background images, you'd have to check inside the click handler *where* the user clicked to make a decision; regular `<img>` tags would work better obviously.

Answer (score 7):

maybe your script tab has some problem.

if you set type, must **type="application/javascript"**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Hello
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div onclick="showMsg('Hello')">
            Click me show message
        </div>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            function showMsg(item) {
            alert(item);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends in how you are hiding your div, `diplay=none` is different of `visibility=hidden` and the `opacity=0`

- Visibility then use `...style.visibility='visible'`
- Display then use `...style.display='block'` (or others depends how
  you setup ur css, inline, inline-block, flex...)
- Opacity then use `...style.opacity='1';`

Answer (score 1):

Its possible, we can specify onclick event in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="thumb0" class="thumbs" onclick="fun1('rad1')" style="height:250px; width:100%; background-color:yellow;";></div>
<div id="rad1" style="height:250px; width:100%;background-color:red;" onclick="fun2('thumb0')">hello world</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
<script>
function fun1(i) {
    document.getElementById(i).style.visibility='hidden';
}
function fun2(i) {
    document.getElementById(i).style.visibility='hidden';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You are using `//--style="display:none"--//` for hiding the div.

Use this code:

```
<script>
    function klikaj(i) {
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
<div id="thumb0" class="thumbs" onclick="klikaj('rad1')">Click Me..!</div>
<div id="rad1" class="thumbs" style="display:none">Helloooooo</div>
```