# calling different functions from different divs

Tags: javascript

I am having a structure like

```
<div onclick="first()">
//first div
<div onclick="second()">
//second div
<div onclick="third()">
//my content here inner div
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

when I am clicking on any div it's calling the first function. How to achieve the situation that only the div I clicked then the corresponding function is called. I am new to javascript.

Comment: `on-click` should be `onclick`. And you need `()` after all the function names.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945825/adding-an-onclick-event-to-a-div-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your DIVs are nested inside each other, the click event will bubble out to each element. If you only want it to be on the inner DIV that you click on, you need to call `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the bubbling. This means you have to pass the `event` object to the functions.

```
<div onclick="first(event)">
//first div
<div onclick="second(event)">
//second div
<div onclick="third(event)">
//my content here inner div
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then the functions have to be like:

```
function first(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // rest of code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp) to stop the `click` event from bubbling up.

```js
function first(){
  this.event.stopPropagation();
  alert( 'first div' );
}

function second(){
  this.event.stopPropagation();
  alert( 'second div' );
}

function third(){
  this.event.stopPropagation();
  alert( 'third div' );
}
```

```html
<div onclick="first()">
//first div
  <div onclick="second()">
  //second div
    <div onclick="third()">
      //my content here inner div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) which prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```js
function first(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('first function')
}
function second(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('second function')
}
function third(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('third function')
}
```

```html
<div onclick="first(event)">
  first div
  <div onclick="second(event)">
    second div
    <div onclick="third(event)">
      my content here inner div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that clicking on a child div, it triggers every parents of this div (clicking on third will triggered second which will trigger first).To prevent the propagation you need to `stopPropagation` like this
[See onclick documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

```js
function first(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('you are in first')
}

function second(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('you are in second')
}

function third(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('you are in third')
}
```

```html
<div onclick="first(event)">
  //first div
  <div onclick="second(event)">
    //second div
    <div onclick="third(event)">
     //my content here inner div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```