# Is @onclick for div allowed?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Here's the code sample:

```
<form>
    <div class="blue-dot ml-sm-1"
     @onclick="this.Validate">></div>
</form>
```

I have the method Validate() defined, but I keep getting this error that is not even on Google.  I started to wonder if this even a valid call.

*RZ2008 Attribute '@onclick' on tag helper element 'div' requires a value. Tag helper bound attributes of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs>' cannot be empty or contain only whitespace.*

Comment: Try without `this.` and please show where `Validate` is defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an onclick event to a div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945825/adding-an-onclick-event-to-a-div-element)

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this is another Visual Studio hipcups...I restarted the Visual Studio and it now compiles.